# Insert 4 equal values with 1 being distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `tbl` with columns like `col1` and `col2`.
`col2` is integer (not an id field, just int field).
I need to insert 4 rows in this table, these rows are:

```
John 1
John 2
John 3
Sam  4
```

What is the best way to do it in a single query? Thanks! :)

**UPDATE**:
And what if I have 100 values? :) What I ment is that all the values are same and go from 1 to n, but one of them is distinct.

Comment: But what about the names inserted in the `col1` field, where did you got them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to insert a substantial number of records (such as 100), you can use a loop inside a stored procedure. Here is a basic example:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS LoopProc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE LoopProc()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    SET x = 1;
    WHILE x  <= 100 DO
      INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('John', x);
      SET  x = x + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET  x = x + 1;
    INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('Sam', x);
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using only one [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement:

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(col1, col2)
VALUES ('John', 1),
       ('John', 2),
       ('John', 3),
       ('Sam',  4);
```

**Or:**

```
INSERT INTO Tablename(col1, col2)
SELECT 'John' AS col1, 1 AS col2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John'        , 2
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'John'        , 3 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sam'         , 4 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES
('John', 1),
('John', 2),
('John', 3),
('Sam', 4)
```